# MVC3: How to stop session expiring after 30 mins?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, session-state

I am trying to change the time it takes for my session to expire.  My views are verifying session with `<Authorize()>`, which works great.

I am doing my session creation as follows:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, True)
Return RedirectToAction("Welcome", "Home")
```

My password is verified with

```
FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(username, password)
```

My route web.config has inside system.web

```
<sessionState timeout="7200"></sessionState>
```

MY authorization node is as follows:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Login" timeout="7200" cookieless="UseCookies" name=".LoginCookie" slidingExpiration="true" >
    <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
      <user name="user" password="pass" />
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

Once logged in I can even verify the specific cookie 'LoginCookie' is set to expire in a few days, yet still, if I am inactive for 30 minutes, my user is getting sent to the login page.

Finally, this appears to work fine in Visual Studio, as it always has for sites I have done, but for some reason once in IIS it doesn't (production environment).

Any help on something I may have missed is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's probably when your IIS apppool is set to recycle. Cache variables are then lost unless they are stored in SQL server or State Server.

Check the settings in the AppPool within IIS. You can extend the idle timeout if required.

Also read this article: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;324772

Comment: MY "regular time interval (minutes)" for this specific application pool is set to 1740  so I am not sure if thats the issue? According to that, it's once every 29 hour, unless there is a different setting i need to look for?  Under "Edit application pool recycling settings" nothing else is checked besides that

Comment: There is also an Idle-Timeout setting. If the App-pool is idle for this period, then it will restart regardless of the regular setting.

Comment: I have done this in the past with SQL Server but was avoiding it since lately I have not had to do it... but now that I think about it, all my other apps have been using MySQL Data provider, so it very well might automatically store session state in that... I setup the SQL provider so if that works I'll mark your's as answered.  Hopefully this fixes the issue cause I gotta launch something in the AM =(

Comment: Note - confusingly this setting is not under the Recycle settings. It's under the "Process Model" settings.

Comment: even using SQL as my session holder, my user is still getting kicked out =/

Comment: Hmm - not tried this, but I imagine that regardless of the fact that the session data is preserved with SQL, the fact the AppPool is recycling is probably still killing your authentication. You can track this recycling by logging from the protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) event in the Global.asax file. I would track down the Idle timeout setting and increase though - should resolve things.

Comment: actually theres something extremely confusing on my server... again in visual studio's i can see its using my session state from SQL Server, but deployment seems to be completely ignoring this. I even put a obviously invalid ip for server 9413.2314.412.311 and got no error. (I know which is using it cause im viewing the records in ASPStateTempSessions).  This is really driving my insane... why would IIS be ignoring my request to use SQL Server

Comment: Post your deployment server's web.config settings for session.

Comment: <sessionState  mode="SQLServer" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" sqlConnectionString="Data Source=SERVER;initial catalog=DB;persist security info=True;user id=USER;password=PASS"  cookieless="false"  timeout="7200" />
 
which works perfect from ASP.net.  Also it can connect cause im using same connection string for my entities that work fine

Comment: Have you set up the session db on that server? aspnet_regsql.exe -S <server> -U <dbuser> -P <password> -ssadd -sstype p

Comment: yes. I know it is setup 100% correct because when running in Visual Studio I can see the session created in ASPStateTempSession.  However once I run on the production server it seems to default to in-proc, even though i have that there (Same exact config as dev server, but i manually opened the file on production to see it in fact is there, and it is)

Comment: OK - has the identity that the production server AppPool is running under got permissions to use the SessionState db. You've said it can see the server, other dbs are ok, but check the sessionstate db also.

Comment: the sessionstate db is the same database as my entity is using. I just had it create new tables in it.  Im not sure if the app pool itself does, but I am using a user id and password so I dont think it matters, does it? The same connection string on my dev box, connecting to the same SQL Server, seems to work (and i am using a user/pass combo, not my windows credentials.  Also this SQL server is the same box as the production)

Comment: whats really p* me off now is if i put an invalid server on localhost i get 'network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.'  but if i do it on development it completely ignores it and runs with in-proc so it appears its completely ignoring any SQL sessions

Comment: You're right sorry - I didn't see the User/Pw in the connstring. I don't understand this behaviour at all - suggest you raise separate question for why your server is not using SQLSession. For some reason the setting in that web.config is being applied. Very odd.

Comment: k will do. Thanks for all the help!